# PHP variable from database row

Tags: php, sql, database, variables

I am trying to create a PHP variable from a database table with only one row and one column. So Basically, I'm trying to pass information within several pages using a database. Is this possible? I have a table called `name` and a column on it also called `name`. I only have one row on it, and I would like to select the value of that only field and assign a variable to it. How do I do this? Thanks!

Edit: I have tried:

```
$name = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM name ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1");

var_dump($name);
```

But it returns `null`.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM lv1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1"); //You get only 1 row

$name = ($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) ? mysql_fetch_assoc($result) : null ;

var_dump($name) ;
```

Comment: thanks, but I forgot to mention, I need multiple variables that come from different tables

Comment: also, I get `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /homepages/12/d441172468/htdocs/Maze/process.php on line 12`. Line 12 is where I put the `$name = ($result) ? mysql_fetch_assoc($result)['name'] : null ;`

Comment: it works, but the output is `array(1) { ["name"]=> string(5) "Jerk." }`. When I open Firebug, it tells me that the value of the `$name` is `""`

Comment: when I do `echo $name`, it doesnt show `Jerk.`. Instead, it shows `Array`. How do I fix this? Sorry, Im kinda new to PHP

Comment: that fixed it, but how do I create 10 more variables, all from different tables?

Comment: That's kinda another question.. but would you like to accept my answer if you think i already helped you?